# Java MongoDB cascading exception

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a question about Cascading in MongoDB;
So. My project is based on Java 10 and Spring Boot 2.0.5 and Lombok.
I've created CascadeSave event listener and here is it

```
public class CascadeSaveMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener {

@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

@Override
public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent event) {

    Object source = event.getSource();
    ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(source.getClass(), field -> {
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(DBRef.class) && field.isAnnotationPresent(CascadeSave.class)) {
            Object fieldValue = field.get(source);
            if (fieldValue instanceof Collection<?>) {
                Collection collection = (Collection<?>) fieldValue;
                for (Object o : collection) {
                    mongoOperations.save(o);
                }
            } else {
                mongoOperations.save(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Event listener is also included in mongo configuration like this:

```
@Bean
public CascadeSaveMongoEventListener cascadingMongoEventListener() {
    return new CascadeSaveMongoEventListener();
}
```

And this how domain class looks like:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Article {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    @CascadeSave
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Comment {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String text;

}
```

The problem is that after saving I've take a look at DB via Mongo Compass and Article.comments is collection of null's, but the comments are saved correctly in separate collection. What is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: does manuaul save of comments and then article work fine? I'm asking, because I'm not sure if 'lazy = true' @Dbref is supported on collections field

Comment: @VladMamaev I'm not sure, but removing "lazy = true" has no effect :)